# How to access the Salesforce Marketing Cloud through simple-salesforce

Tags: python, salesforce, salesforce-marketing-cloud, simple-salesforce

I am implementing a project using simple-salesforce so I can manage and trigger events on Salesforce Marketing Cloud. The problem I have encountered is that the documentation is not explicit if I can use simple-salesforce to access the Marketing Cloud endpoints.

I've noticed even that the login method on simple-salesforce can't be done by the Salesforce Marketing Cloud credentials. When I try to do this I get:

```
SalesforceAuthenticationFailed: INVALID_LOGIN: Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out.
```

Did someone have the same issue? Can I access the Salesforce Marketing Cloud through simple-salesforce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`simple_salesforce` is for the Salesforce CRM platform. It provides no support for Marketing Cloud, which has distinct APIs, of any kind. You'll need to use one of the Marketing Cloud SDKs instead.

I am not a Marketing Cloud expert, but this appears to be the [relevant official documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/connecting_to_the_api_using_python.html#!) for the Marketing Cloud SOAP API, and for the [Python SDK](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/getting-started-with-the-python-sdk.html). There's also a [REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/rest-api-overview.html) that you can call with any Python HTTP client. There may also be third-party or community libraries available.

Comment: Than you! I've had the feeling that this was the case, but I got confused by one Issue opened at the simple-salesforce repo.

Answer (score 0):

To access Salesforce Marketing Cloud via Simple Salesforce:

1. Have access to a Salesforce Marketing Cloud account
2. Install Simple Salesforce via pip
3. Pip install simple-salesforce
   Code:-  pip install simple-salesforce
4. Connect to the API using provided credentials
   Code:-

from simple_salesforce import Salesforce, SalesforceMarketingCloud

```
  sfmc = SalesforceMarketingCloud(
  username='<your SFMC username>',
  password='<your SFMC password>',
 client_id='<your SFMC client ID>',
 client_secret='<your SFMC client secret>',
 auth_url='https://<your SFMC subdomain>.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/',
 soap_endpoint='https://<your SFMC subdomain>.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/',
 rest_endpoint='https://<your SFMC subdomain>.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/',
 debug=False
 )
```

5. Once connected, use Simple Salesforce's methods to access and manipulate data in your Marketing Cloud account. For instance, use the get() method to retrieve all the campaigns in your account:

Code:-

```
Campaigns = sfmc.campaigns.get()
print(campaigns)
```

6. Review Simple Salesforce documentation for other available methods.

https://simple-salesforce.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html